# gradle sync failed after install official Android Studio 3.0 with strange errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I installed official version of android studio 3.0, so now all of my project(even a new project!) failed at gradle sync.

to know, i deleted all of my gardle files and studio setting in user Directory and downloaded all of them again :(

in this picture i have got this problem:

[first same error in every project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReBBS.png)

and here's some details:
[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDyIE.png)

here is my gradle version in `build.gradle(project:AndroidStudio)`

```
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

and i have `gradle-4.1-all.zip` in my GRADLE_USER_HOME

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

Comment: i have checked it, it was all set but still not working

Comment: You need to add `google()` as a repository. Plus you need to set  `compileSdkVersion` to 26 and `buildToolsVersion` to '26.0.2'.

Comment: i checked and i'm pretty sure about them!